# What is the Python "with" statement used for?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to understand the with statement in python.  Everywhere I look it talks of opening and closing a file, and is meant to replace the try-finally block. Could someone post some other examples too.  I am just trying out flask and there are with statements galore in it.  Definitely request someone to provide some clarity on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a very nice explanation [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).  Basically, the with statement calls two special methods on the associated object.  The __enter__ and __exit__ methods.  The enter method returns the variable associated with the "with" statement. While the __exit__ method is called after the statement executes to handle any cleanup (such as closing a file pointer).

Comment: I'm with the OP. The link you gave demonstrates the "opening and closing a file" example that Alice described, but it doesn't actually show *why* it's better than "data = open("x.txt").read()". It seems like "with" is something I should be considering, but darned if I can tell what it's actually good for.

Comment: The key reason to use it to avoid having to remember to or deal with any clean up after you are done with something.  The with block does that for you.  So instead of fp = open() ... fp.close().  You just use a with block.

Comment: But what is the big deal here. A try finally block is much clearer ,cleaner and as said:explicit is better than implicit! :-)

Answer (score 10):

The idea of the `with` statement is to make "doing the right thing" the path of least resistance. While the file example is the simplest, threading locks actually provide a more classic example of non-obviously buggy code:

```
try:
    lock.acquire()
    # do stuff
finally:
    lock.release()
```

This code is broken - if the lock acquisition ever fails, either the wrong exception will be thrown (since the code will attempt to release a lock that it never acquired), or, worse, if this is a recursive lock, it will be released early. The correct code looks like this:

```
lock.acquire()
try:
    # do stuff
finally:
    # If lock.acquire() fails, this *doesn't* run
    lock.release()
```

By using a `with` statement, it becomes impossible to get this wrong, since it is built into the context manager:

```
with lock: # The lock *knows* how to correctly handle acquisition and release
  # do stuff
```

The other place where the `with` statement helps greatly is similar to the major benefit of function and class decorators: it takes "two piece" code, which may be separated by an arbitrary number of lines of code (the function definition for decorators, the `try` block in the current case) and turns it into "one piece" code where the programmer simply declares up front what they're trying to do.

For short examples, this doesn't look like a big gain, but it actually makes a huge difference when reviewing code. When I see `lock.acquire()` in a piece of code, I need to scroll down and check for a corresponding `lock.release()`. When I see `with lock:`, though, no such check is needed - I can see immediately that the lock will be released correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are twelve examples of using `with` in [PEP343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), including the file-open example:

1. A template for ensuring that a lock, acquired at the start of a
      block, is released when the block is left
2. A template for opening a file that ensures the file is closed
      when the block is left
3. A template for committing or rolling back a database
      transaction
4. Example 1 rewritten without a generator
5. Redirect stdout temporarily
6. A variant on opened() that also returns an error condition
7. Another useful example would be an operation that blocks
      signals
8. Another use for this feature is the Decimal context
9. Here's a simple context manager for the decimal module
10. A generic "object-closing" context manager
11. a released() context to temporarily release a previously acquired lock by swapping the acquire() and release() calls
12. A "nested" context manager that automatically nests the
         supplied contexts from left-to-right to avoid excessive
         indentation